# Export .xls file with image in cell ROR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-excel

i need to export a set of data, and it contains an image field too, am little bit confused in exporting image into excelsheet. Everything works fine except image field.

**toxl.xls.erb** 
`<% @posts.each do |post| %>`
 `<Row>`
   `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= post.name %></Data></Cell>`
   `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= post.created_at %></Data></Cell>`
   `<Cell> Need image here inside cell  <%=post.image%> <Cell>`
   `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= post.updated_at %></Data></Cell>`
 `</Row>`
`< %end %>`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use special gems for rendering XLSX files like [write_xlsx](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx) ([write_xlsx_rails](https://github.com/maxd/write_xlsx_rails) is wrapper for Rails). Such gems provide required functionality out of the box (example is [here](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx/blob/master/examples/demo.rb#L86-L91)).